# cannot select UITableViewCell programmatically

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, selection

I am attempting to select, in the view did appear method, a table cell programatically.

```
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:1 inSection:1];

[self.tableView selectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:NO scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionNone];
```

my delegate,

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
```

does not get called.

The delegate gets called if i select the cells in the simulator with a mouse, however, just not programmatically.

Why can this be?

Comment: This question would have been trivially answered by reading the docs on `selectRowAtIndexPath:`. Please do try to read the docs before using bandwidth.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because that's how the framework works. Try reading the docs. That's what they are for!

> `selectRowAtIndexPath:animated:scrollPosition:`
>
> Selects a row in the receiver identified by index path, optionally scrolling the row to a location in the receiver... Calling this method *does not cause the delegate* to receive a `tableView:willSelectRowAtIndexPath:` or `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` message.

That's pretty easy to understand. The delegate method `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` is not called if you select the row in code (programmatically). It is called only if the *user* selects the row.

And this makes perfect sense, because:

- If you are selecting the row in code, you might not want the delegate method triggered.
- If you *do* want the delegate method triggered, since you are in your own code, you can just call it.
- You don't need the delegate method in order to *learn* that the row was selected, because *you* selected it in code - you cannot *not* know!

Comment: @stackOverFlew - Please note that this pattern is followed by most (if not all) of `UIKit`. Delegates are only called when something is done by the user, never when the action is explicitly done through code. This is a good thing. Otherwise you might end up with infinite recursion because it is common to have the implementation of a delegate method to adjust the value that just changed.

Comment: the cell itself shows no sign that it has been selected either, however.

Comment: Perhaps `viewDidAppear` is too soon. But in any case that would be a different question; you'd need to supply information about when and how you are populating your table in the first place, whether the cells are standard or custom, etc.