# About UITableViewCell selected

Tags: ios, objective-c

When i call "tableView:didSelected" this method in the code,the cell.selected == NO ,but when i select the cell in simulator,the cell.selected == YES(system call the method),why?

Comment: Don't understand your question.Can you ask clearly?

Comment: Can you edit and ask again?

Comment: Oh,please forgive my poor English.I want to call this method :"tableViwe:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath" to assign cell.selected = YES,but the result is cell.selected == NO.How to assign the cell.selected = YES in the code?(only system call this method the cell.selected == YES)

Comment: Basically a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16504078/cannot-select-uitableviewcell-programmatically

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should never call it.  The runtime calls it. Not you.

Comment: How to do this ? "[cell setValue:@YES  forKeyPath:@"selected"];" like this?but it is the same result.

Comment: That is not what you asked. If you want to know how to change a cell's selected state, you should have asked how to change a cell's selected state. You asked why calling `tableView:didSelect` doesn't work, and I told you the answer: that is not what it is for.

Comment: Sorry,please excuse my bad expression...I just look at your answer,it is a pretty answer.thanks for your answer.